# Is it possible to "automatically" include a namespace in all files in Java project?

Tags: java, gradle

We have a Java 17 / Gradle project that uses HL7 library to transform our data into XML. That means we have the following includes all over the place:

```
import org.hl7.fhir.dstu2016may.model.*;
```

Now we forked the project to use NEWER version of that library, and the include line changed to

```
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Task;
```

For MANY files in our solution that's the ONLY change between OLD and NEW projects. But it makes it very difficult to compare solutions (literally, as folders) to identify which files have changes in functionally between OLD and NEW solutions. We need this, for example, to ensure we port bugfixes and new features and so on.

I would love to be able to specify some sort of "global" import in gradle file that will eliminate the need of adding these import into each individual file and only have gradle files different between old and new solutions. Is it possible?

If not - are there any other ways to achieve what I want - "wrap" library-dependent part of the solution into some sort of common file?

Comment: Why is it difficult to compare old and new 'solutions'? are you using source control? Global imports doesn't exist in Java. Wrap the library probably yes, but without knowing the library it is hard to say if it is worth the effort. In any case that is a different question and off topic here.

Comment: It should be pretty simple to `grep` for the old import to find occurrences, even in a folder structure. Tools like `sed` could even replace them on the fly. If that's the only change you should be done very quickly.